# Why would $user->sid be undefined?

Tags: 7

I added some debugging statements (using dd()) which include a timestamp and $user->sid (after declaring $user as a global).  I tested it, of course, and everything worked great for me. Then a user reported getting some notices which said "Undefined property: stdClass::$sid ..."

I added a conditional to test to see if $user->sid is set before writing out the value, but I didn't think that it was possible for it to not be set!  I did some quick Google and drupal.stackexchange.com searches, but couldn't find any info on how this might be possible.

Anybody have any insight here?

TIA,
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not logged in the property will be undefined. This is all I've got for the anonymous user

```
object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
  ["uid"]=>
  int(0)
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(9) "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
  ["roles"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(14) "anonymous user"
  }
  ["cache"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Victor.  Based on this issue (https://www.drupal.org/node/257014), I thought it should be defined - apparently not!